# Как изменить RT_STRING ресурс .exe файла

Tags: winapi, resources

Как изменить RT_STRING ресурс .exe файла.

Нашел вот такой пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088057/updating-a-string-table-with-updateresource получилось его запустить но он меняет записи во всей STRINGTABLE, а мне нужно изменить только одну запись.
Спасибо.

Comment: reshacker попробуйте

Comment: Мне нужно программно. С++ via WinApi.

Comment: Тогда парсинг ресурсов и замена нужного.

Comment: Был бы благодарен за внятный пример изменения RT_STRING ресурса.

Comment: Там не одна страница кода будет.

Comment: можешь на мыло закинуть? =)

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27165/discussion-between-mynameis-and--).

Comment: Guys need help!

Comment: За вас код писать? Нет уж...

Comment: сказал как отрезал =))

Comment: Есть ли возможность обновить одну строку в пачке без переписывания всей пачки строк?

Comment: Изучите уже наконец предметную область, тем более что вам сказали в какую сторону смотреть. Не хотите делать сами - ищите исполнителя на соответствующих сайтах.

Comment: Чего тебе не спится, a?

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам библиотека [portable-executable-library](https://code.google.com/p/portable-executable-library/)

Вот вам [пример изменения ресурсов](https://code.google.com/p/portable-executable-library/source/browse/trunk/samples/resource_editor/main.cpp)

Comment: уже не актуально, разобрался. но все равно большое спасибо.